# How to know which object sent notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to move UI elements inside the `UIScrollView` when the keyboard has appeared so it can be visible to the user.

To achieve this behavior I call the following methods:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` methods.

However, in my case there are two text views on the same view controller, but I need to move UI elements in case of one of them only. How can I do it? Can I somehow call `addObserver` for only one object or check which object called it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask a text view whether it has the keyboard focus:

```
if ([myTextView1 isFirstResponder]) {
    // Do this
} else if ([myTextView2 isFirstResponder]) {
    // Do that.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your sender along with your notification object or user info

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject userInfo:(NSDictionary *)aUserInfo;
```